# Does facebook graph search api support logical query?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Does anyone have any idea about logical query in Facebook Graph search API?

**Problem:**

I am trying to fetch all public post using following URL:

"https://graph.facebook.com/search?q="+testKeywords+"&access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&type=post"

testKeywords = (Mahindra AND (Auto OR Navistar OR HCV OR LCV OR passenger OR Renault))

I want to search for the public post which contains the word "Mahindra" and combination of any of the "OR" word.

**for e.g.**

1) Apply for car loans/auto loans online at Mahindra - (keywords : Mahindra and auto)

2) Mahindra Renault Logan Price in India - Rs 6.95 Lakhs . (keywords : Mahindra and Renault)

I have tried using following method, but no success :

"https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Mahindra+Auto|Navistar|HCV|LCV|passenger|Renault&access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&type=post"

Does anyone know if it is still possible to perform such kind of query with Facebook Graph search API?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: AND/OR are not supported with the `search API`

Comment: Shadowfax, do you know any other alternative to AND/OR kind of query for Facebook Graph search API?

Comment: I dont think there exists any

Comment: ok, thanks for your effort Shadowfax.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite late but you can use the AND operator inside a search, it can be done by using the "+" operator as you mentioned and by putting "&q=" field many times as keywords you may enter. What I haven't found is a way to make the OR work.